# Status Color instead of Status Text

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, status

[image]

So I am trying to add the color to the field instead of the status text. How would you guy by doing this?

Comment: Use Sharepoint designer to add conditional formatting to that column.

Comment: As mike has suggested in below answer you can use JSLink. For example https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-0a786cdd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this below code in **content editor webpart** or in **JS file and connect it with JSLink** property to your webpart.

Here it is using priority field. You can use your desired field.

**Code:**

```
(function () {

    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render 
    var priorityFiledContext = {};
    priorityFiledContext.Templates = {};
    priorityFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
        // Apply the new rendering for Priority field on List View
        "Priority": { "View": priorityFiledTemplate }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(priorityFiledContext);

})();

// This function provides the rendering logic for list view
function priorityFiledTemplate(ctx) {

    var priority = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
    var color = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];

    // Return html element with appropriate color based on priority value
    switch (priority) {
        case "(1) High":
            return "<span style='color :#f00; background-color:#f00;'>" + priority + "</span>";
            break;
        case "(2) Normal":
            return "<span style='color :#ff6a00; background-color:#f6a00;'>" + priority + "</span>";
            break;
        case "(3) Low":
            return "<span style='color :#cab023; background-color:#cab023;'>" + priority + "</span>";
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks for the help. This actually worked with the JSLink.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via JSLink. JSLink allows you to use JavaScript to do things like conditional formatting of list items, including things like conditionally displaying an image. A quick search for JSLink KPI turns up lots of examples, including [this one](http://www.abelsolutions.com/2013-blog/creating-a-simple-kpi-column-in-sharepoint-2013-list-views-using-js-link/).

Comment: Do you think I could use the code below as an embedded code into my page?

Comment: Save the file in a folder (style library for example). Copy the js file URL-path. Go to your page with the list and open the settingswindow for the webpart. Under advanced you should see a input for js-link. Post the URL you copied and save.