# Color coding list custom field in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, javascript, script, spcolor

We have a field called next due date. I'm trying to color that field if it exceeds the date.

Red color if exceeds the date and yellow color if it is 1 day near to the due date.

Please guide me on how to achieve this.

TIA!!

Comment: You will get date difference from this URL: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171222/count-not-updating-in-calculated-column/171482#171482 . And using the date difference you can set color code show in this URL: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/181492/status-color-instead-of-status-text/181514#181514

Answer (score 0):

There is also 3rd party software that can provide this.  For instance 'Sparqube' has a Status Indicator column which can be configured to change the colour of the date value if it exceeds a date.  This column can then be added to a list or document library in the normal way via the settings menu.

There are probably other companies that would provide this kind of add-in column too.  I don't work for Sparqube, just making a suggestion.  If you can do the coding, that option will be cheaper!